# Django translations - translate days of week

Tags: javascript, django, d3.js, c3.js

I'm making multilingual website and have a problem in translating days of week
So:

```
var day = moment().startOf("week").format('dddd')
```

This is short version.

I've tried to use ugettext_lazy (_) -

```
var one = _(moment().startOf("week").format('dddd'))
```

But it doesn't work.

full:

```
var days = data.buckets.map(e => moment().startOf('week').day(1 + e.key).format('dddd'))
```

This is d3/c3 format.

I'm using days in x-axis in vertical bar chart(maybe it is important:))

I need to translate all day's names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sample you provided

```
var one = _(moment().startOf("week").format('dddd'))
```

is JavaScript. In JS it's more common to use the `_` name for either underscore.js or lodash, rather for translations. It's probably not what you intended.

If you want to do the translation in Python, then you should provide the already translated string as a variable to your JS script. If the *values* are only coming from JS, then I suggest a dictionary/object mapping day numbers to translated strings. Make a Django template that includes the following:

```
{% load trans %}

<script>
var dayNamesMap = {
    0: "{% trans 'Monday' %}",
    1: "{% trans 'Tuesday' %}",
    2: "{% trans 'Wednesday' %}",
    // etc.
};
</script>
```

Or do it in your view, making sure the locale is set (see [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)):

```
day_names_map = json.dumps({
    date.weekday(): date.strftime('%A')
    for i in range(7)
    for date in [datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=i)]
})
```

which returns

```
'{"3": "Thursday", "4": "Friday", "5": "Saturday", "6": "Sunday", "0": "Monday", "1": "Tuesday", "2": "Wednesday"}'
```

then add `day_names_map` to your context, and in your template do:

```
<script>
var dayNamesMap = {{ day_names_map }}
</script>
```